# Oracle query multiple delete statements from .NET

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, odp.net, odac

I've got issue with executing simple query in Oracle from .NET (ODP):

```
        const string sql = @"
            delete from CLIENTS where CAMPAIGN_ID = :campaignId
            delete from OPERATORS where CAMPAIGN_ID = :campaignId
            delete from CAMPAIGNS_EXCLUDE_DAYS where CAMPAIGN_ID = :campaignId
            delete from CAMPAIGNS where ID = :campaignId";

        var p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("campaignId", campaignId);

        Connection.Execute(sql, p);
```

I am using Dapper as light weight ORM there. Probably even without knowing Dapper it's all clear.

Here is an exception:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: You can't do it like this.  Either put those sql commands into a stored procedure, or run them individually.

Answer (score 1):

```
const string sql = @"
     delete from CLIENTS where CAMPAIGN_ID = @campaignId
     delete from OPERATORS where CAMPAIGN_ID = @campaignId
     delete from CAMPAIGNS_EXCLUDE_DAYS where CAMPAIGN_ID = @campaignId
     delete from CAMPAIGNS where ID = @campaignId";

var p = new { campaignId=campaignId };
Connection.Execute(sql, p);
```

Comment: I agree. I am new to oracle as far as I am .NET developer. In MSSQL with ; it would work great. But Oracle throws exception...

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich. Sorry for the earlier mistake. Try this query.